I need help proving this :$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$
I need help proving this :$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$$
we have :
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}(-1)^nx^{2n}$$
For one hour looking at this series, I couldn't find even a single idea on how to prove this using the various conventional methods I know.

An alternative solution, using the fact that
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n+1}(u) \mathrm{d}u=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}.
$$
Let $x=iy$, then
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0} \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} (-1)^n x^{2n+1}
=
i\sum_{n=0} \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}  y^{2n+1}
=
i\sum_{n=0} \int_0^{\pi/2} y^{2n+1}\cos^{2n+1}(u) \mathrm{d}u  
\\
&=
i\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\sum_{n=0}  y^{2n+1}\cos^{2n+1}(u)\right] \mathrm{d}u  
=i\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\frac{ y\cos (u)}{1- y^2\cos^2 (u)}\right] \mathrm{d}u  
\\
&=
-i\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\frac{ y\ \mathrm{d}(\sin u)}{1- y^2(1-\sin^2 (u))}\right] \mathrm{d}u  
=i\frac{\arcsin(-y)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}.
\end{align}
Recalling that $y=-ix$ and substituting will get the result.

Amazing method, thinking outside the box

Let
$$
f(x)=\frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$
and
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^n x^{2n+1}
$$
Then
$$
(xg(x))'=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^n x^{2n+2}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^n x^{2n+1}
$$
and
\begin{align}
(1+x^2)(xg(x))'&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^n x^{2n+1}
+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^n x^{2n+3}
\\ &=
2x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^n x^{2n+1}
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}(-1)^n x^{2n+1}
\\ &=
2x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}(-1)^n x^{2n+1}
=x+g(x).
\end{align}
It is elementaty to check that the same equality holds for $f$ as well:
$$
(xf(x))'=\frac{x+f(x)}{1+x^2}.
$$
Since $f(0)=0=g(0)$, we conclude that $f\equiv g$.

Is there a direct way?

Beautiful method sir
